# Using http.request generates error

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, module

I have been writing my own static http server using **net** module from **Node.js**.
Here is my code :

```
var options = {
  hostname: 'localhost',
  port: 8000,
  path: '/read.txt',
  httpVersion : 1.1,
  method: 'GET',
  headers:{
    'Content-Type':'text/plain',
    'connection' : 'keep-alive'
 }
};

function test(){
    var sev = server.start(8000,"./folder",function(e){
        e?(console.log(e)):(console.log("server is connected in port 8888"));
    });
     var req = http.request(options, function(res) {});
     req.on('error', function(e) {
         console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
      });
     server.stop(sev,function(e){e?(console.log(e)):(console.log("server is closed"));})
}
test()
```

Here is the function **stop** from the **server** module:

```
exports.stop = function(serverID,callback){
    serverID.close();
    callback();
}
```

But when I run it it shows the message: 
**problem with request: connect ECONNREFUSED.**
I can't find the problem, Is it possible that the problem is with the node version ?

Comment: Looks like 'server.stop' is running before 'server.start' has had a chance to finish (or `http.request` before `server.start` finishes).  Your `test` method is running things without a chance to let each finish.

Answer (score 0):

Before you close the server you should close the socket.
Also try to delay the program before using **stop**.

Try adding:

```
req.end();
setTimeout(function(){server.stop(sev,function(e){e?(console.log(e)):(console.log("server     is closed"));})
},4000);
```